# Unable to deploy tomcat on GCP

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu-14.04, google-cloud-platform

I am new to the google cloud platform. I just took the Ubuntu 14.04LTS OS on GCP, Installed Java 7 JDK . I have my own application on tomcat8. Later, I copied my war files to the tomcat/webapps folder. But the "http://GCP_Public_ip:8080/my_app" is throwing an error "This site can’t be reached". How can I deploy my application on GCP!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to open port TCP-8080 on Google Cloud Platform, does not come open by default.
On the left menu click on "Networking" then "Firewall Rules". Click the button at the top "Create a New Firewall Rule" for tomcat (image below).
Regards,
Roque.

[New Firewall Rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLZMm.png)